# Customize label for an Interaction Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, interaction-plot

Suppose I have the following data which summarizes the values of a dependent variable (dv) at low and high vales of a predictor (x) and a moderator (z)

```
dfx <- data.frame(x = rep(c(-0.909, 0.909),2),
                  z = c(-0.676, -0.676, 0.676, 0.676),
                  dv = c(448.8, 464.4, 462.8, 472.1))
```

I would like to draw the dv as a function of the predictor and the moderator by customizing **both** the type of lines **and** the markers

```
library(ggplot2)
dfx$z <- as.factor(dfx$z) # turn the moderator as a factor

ggplot(dfx, aes(x=x, y = dv, colour=z, shape=z))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous("dv", limits = c(440,480))+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_colour_manual  ("A title", values=c("black", "black"), labels=c("-1SD", "+1SD"))+
  scale_shape_manual   ("A title", values=c(2,15),labels=c("-1SD","+1SD"))
```

[image]

However, I would like to customize the linetype as well.

When I add:

`ggplot(dfx, aes(x=x, y = dv, colour=z, shape=z, linetype=z)`

the following plot emerges. Yet I cannot either hide the second label or customize it through `scale_linetype_manual`

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? I searched the community but could not find any method to overcome this problem. Also, when I suppress the second label, the legend key does not show the line type and mark.
Any hint will be very much appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear what your desired output should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dfx, aes(x=x, y = dv, shape=z, linetype=z)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous("dv", limits = c(440,480))+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_linetype_manual("A title",
                      values=c(1, 3),
                      labels=c("-1SD", "+1SD")) +
  scale_shape_manual("A title",
                     values=c(2,15),
                     labels=c("-1SD","+1SD"))
```

[image: result]

Comment: Yes, this is what exactly I needed. I tried it and get the output exactly as you shown above. Thanks a lot L. Tyrone!
As far as I understood, the `colour=z` in the "aes" parenthesis was needless and created the problems.

Comment: @thanmour - yes, that's correct. The default behaviour for `ggplot()` is to add anything declared inside `aes()` to the legend. You can suppress aesthetics from a legend using `guides(colour = "none")` or `show.legend = FALSE` but in your case, you were using colour so removing it was the better solution.

Comment: @L Tyrone -  thanks for the detailed explanation! It makes totally sense.